# Tumblr API Blog methods return 401 "Not Authorized", but User methods works perfect

Tags: python, oauth, tumblr, xauth, token

So, there is a code that uses xAuth authentication to call tumblr API methods:

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer_key     = "..."
consumer_secret  = "..."

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

resp, content = client.request('https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token', "POST", urllib.urlencode({
    'x_auth_mode': 'client_auth',
    'x_auth_username': '...@yandex.ru',
    'x_auth_password': '...'
}))

token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
print token

token = oauth.Token(token['oauth_token'], token['oauth_token_secret'])
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

response, data = client.request('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/good.tumblr.com/followers', method='GET') 
print data
```

It works perfect with User methods from [tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) that require OAuth authentication.
But it fails when i try to call any Blog method with OAuth authentication (/followers for example):

```
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

Except one thing. If i use my blog name as {base-hostname} parameter it works without any errors.
Weird. How is that possible? Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: clumpter, have you gotten any of the POST based API methods to work for tumblr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is because your OAuth access token grants you access to your blogs. OAuth can't give you permission to access Blog methods that you do not own because then you could post to them.

Answer (score 0):

When you make POST request the enctype must be "multipart/form-data".

I had the same problem with Zend_Oauth (php), but is resolved now.

Comment: It's not OAuth that is failing for the OP; it's the fact that the OAuth token doesn't give enough access to use the Blog methods.